# How to show google ads in ionic4 project for desktop platform?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

As I am new to the Ionic Framework, I know little about ionic. In the documentation, they show how to show ads on a mobile platform. But they did not show the documentation of how to show ad in the desktop platform. They show the use of adMobfree and adMobPro for mobile platforms. Is there any way to show ads in the desktop platform in the ionic project. Please, someone, show me a way to show ads in desktop platforms in the ionic project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ng2-adsense` npm package doesn't help for me. But I found simple way of solving this issue. 
At first, you need to add the script in the `head` tag like this.

```
<head>
      <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
</head>
```

After that, you need to write this code in your body tag.

```
<body>
<div>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
    data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX" 
    data-ad-format="link"
    data-full-width-responsive="true" 
    data-full-width-responsive="true">
  </ins>
<!-- data-ad-slot=Your ad Unit number that you have created -->
</div>
<app-root style="display: none;"></app-root>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    console.log(adsbygoogle);
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

That's it. After writing this code you will see the ads. 
By the way to see the ads you need to provide `data-ad-client` id of an active google ad-sense account. 
You need to `disable your ad-blocker` to see the ads. 
If you see the `console.log` like that means your ad is coming.

```
{loaded: true, push: ƒ}
```

I have set the `style=" display: none;"` so that you can see the ads. If you see the ads that mean ad-sense is working. Now you can add your logic to show ads where you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using Web Platform standard web components only and no framework like Angular, Vue, or React. If you seek the same solution, this might help. Here is a stencil.js component that works for me. In my case, right now, I just have it hard-coded to render a single ad, but you could extend this idea with tag attributes so that it can be more customizable per tag use, much like the ng2-adsense described above by IBRAHIM KHALIL (something I was going to get around to later).

This requires that you also have the standard javascript include for Google Adsense in the head of index.html in your single page app. For example:

```
  <!-- Global site tag - Google Adsense -->
  <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Then, here's the stencil component, gls-adsense-ad.tsx...

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';

declare global {
    interface Window { adsbygoogle: any; }
}

@Component({
    tag: 'gls-adsense-ad',
})
export class GlsAdsenseAd {

    adsbygoogle:any;

    componentDidRender() {
        (this.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                style={{ display: `block` }}
                data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"
                data-ad-format="auto"
                data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can see this working in the right-hand column of blog post pages on my site, which is a static site built with Ionic 4 and Stencil.js: https://codyburleson.com